# output of the following code related to macros

Tags: c

Please explain the output — I am getting the output as 20,
but it should be 64 if I am not wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQUARE(X) (X*X) 
main() 
{ 
    int a, b=6; 
    a = SQUARE(b+2); 
    printf("\n%d", a);
}
```

Comment: You are wrong — it should be 20.  Run `cc -E code.c` and look at the expansion of SQUARE.

Comment: Incidentally, you need to be careful with magic quotes `“\n%d”` vs regular quotes `"%d\n"` — the C compiler won't accept magic quotes.  You should normally end output lines with a newline rather than, or as well as, starting the line with a newline.  You should use an explicit return type on `main()` — of `int` (see [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)).

Answer (score 3):

The correct result is 20.

Macros are simple text substitutions.

To see that the result is 20, just replace the `X` with `b+2`. Then you have:

```
b+2*b+2
```

as `b` is 6 it is

```
6+2*6+2
```

which is 20

When using macros it is important to use parenthesis so the macro should look

```
# define SQUARE(X) ((X)*(X))
```

Then the result will be 64 as the evaluation is

```
(b+2)*(b+2)

(6+2)*(6+2)

8*8

64
```